# autocheck gives me memory and runtime error even though my program runs perfectly

Tags: c

for Uni I have to program a little Calculator think which has to go through a automatic check and be approved for me to pass the test. oblem is that for some reason everything runs perfectly fine in my IDE, there's no Errors, no warning and even debugging i couldn't find any problems but the automatic check gives me 2 errors in my division function which looks like this:

```
int divis(int num1, int num2) {
    int rest;
    rest = 0;
    char opt;
    opt = 'X';

    rest = num1 % num2;             //calc remainder
    printf("\nDivision has remainder %d. Round (r), cut off (c) or discard (d)?", rest); //print remainder
    while((opt =! 'd') || (opt != 'c') || (opt != 'r')){
        printf("\nOption: ");
        scanf(" %c", &opt);

        if(opt == 'r'){                         //round
            if(rest * 2 < num2){
                num1 = num1 / num2;             //calc result
                rest = 0;
                printf("\nResult: %d", num1);   //print result
                break;
            }
            else {
                num1 = num1 / num2;             //calculate result
                ++num1;                         //+round up
                rest = 0;
                printf("\nResult: %d", num1);   //print result
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(opt == 'c'){                //calculate remainder
            rest = 0;
            num1 = num1 / num2;             //calculate result
            printf("\nResult: %d", num1);   //print result
            break;
        }
        else if(opt == 'd'){                //discard operation
            printf("\nNo new result");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("\nUnknown option\n"); 
    }

    if(num1 >= 0)
        ++poscount;
    else
        ++negcount;                 //count results
    return num1;
}
```

keep in mind that it's an exercise in which i need to follow all the required steps. For the calculation 32 / 8 the automatic check gives me the Error: ** <<>> MemoryError **
A memory error occured during program execution.
Please check your program for illegal memory accesses.  and for 32 / -8 it gives me a runtime error even though my program runs perfectly fine. I've been doing some research on the internet for hours but nothing i tried helped. I would really apreciate your help

Comment: For 32/-8/r the result is wrong but there are no memory errors. Well, unless `poscount` or `negcount` is a pointer. So the error must be in the code you didn’t show (even if the check points at this particular function; checks often catch the error but not the cause).

Comment: @handelskonig - I doubt that your _program runs perfectly_ with `while((opt =! 'd')…`